# Cisco site-to-site vpn multiple subnet route over tunnel

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, vpn, firewall

We have a `site-to-site` VPN tunnel to `AWS` which was working great until I added another subnet to the ACL list for interesting traffic which was causing a strange issue. It is only allowing me to add a single ACL subnet for interesting traffic, if I try to add another one then my tunnel goes down.

[image]

currently i have the following ACL and its working great!

`access-list ACL-VPN extended permit tcp 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 10.100.1.0 255.255.255.0`

but as soon as i add my other public subnet to route data over the VPN tunnel it brought the new tunnel up because it is seeing the new IP for interesting traffic which i can see in `show crypto ipsec sa`, as soon as it see new interesting traffic it drop traffic for old tunnel which is `10.0.0.0/24` subnet. look like it only allow single ACL subnet for interesting traffic, i tried `any` but it is throwing error.

`access-list ACL-VPN extended permit tcp 60.x.x.x 255.255.255.0 10.100.1.0 255.255.255.0`

How do i route multiple subnet over the existing VPN tunnel?

This is my crypto map

```
crypto map AWS-VPN 1 match address ACL-VPN
crypto map AWS-VPN 1 set pfs
crypto map AWS-VPN 1 set peer 34.xx.xx.xx 52.xx.xx.xx
crypto map AWS-VPN 1 set ikev1 transform-set AWS-ESP-AES-SHA
crypto map AWS-VPN 1 set security-association lifetime seconds 3600
```

## EDIT

You can see in following output all three subnet tunnel, and currently 70 network tunnel i can ping other are not pingable, but if i pick 10 network and ping it will break 70 network ping and start 10 network. so strange

```
fw1/pri/act# sh crypto ipsec sa peer 13.xx.xx.30
peer address: 13.xx.xx.30

  Crypto map tag: AWS-VPN, seq num: 1, local addr: 66.xx.xx.51

  access-list ACL-VPN extended permit ip 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.100.1.0 255.255.255.0
  local ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (10.0.0.0/255.255.255.0/0/0)
  remote ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (10.100.1.0/255.255.255.0/0/0)
  current_peer: 13.xx.xx.30


  #pkts encaps: 635, #pkts encrypt: 635, #pkts digest: 635
  #pkts decaps: 76, #pkts decrypt: 76, #pkts verify: 76
  #pkts compressed: 0, #pkts decompressed: 0
  #pkts not compressed: 635, #pkts comp failed: 0, #pkts decomp failed: 0
  #pre-frag successes: 0, #pre-frag failures: 0, #fragments created: 0
  #PMTUs sent: 0, #PMTUs rcvd: 0, #decapsulated frgs needing reassembly: 0
  #TFC rcvd: 0, #TFC sent: 0
  #Valid ICMP Errors rcvd: 0, #Invalid ICMP Errors rcvd: 0
  #send errors: 0, #recv errors: 0

  local crypto endpt.: 66.xx.xx.51/4500, remote crypto endpt.: 13.xx.xx.30/4500
  path mtu 1500, ipsec overhead 82(52), media mtu 1500
  PMTU time remaining (sec): 0, DF policy: clear-df
  ICMP error validation: disabled, TFC packets: disabled
  current outbound spi: 2C59F831
  current inbound spi : 574D3919

inbound esp sas:
  spi: 0x574D3919 (1464678681)
     transform: esp-aes esp-sha-hmac no compression
     in use settings ={L2L, Tunnel,  NAT-T-Encaps, PFS Group 2, IKEv1, }
     slot: 0, conn_id: 1126400, crypto-map: AWS-VPN
     sa timing: remaining key lifetime (kB/sec): (4373993/1587)
     IV size: 16 bytes
     replay detection support: Y
     Anti replay bitmap:
      0x00000000 0x00001FFF 0xFFFFFFFF 0xFFFFFFFF
outbound esp sas:
  spi: 0x2C59F831 (744093745)
     transform: esp-aes esp-sha-hmac no compression
     in use settings ={L2L, Tunnel,  NAT-T-Encaps, PFS Group 2, IKEv1, }
     slot: 0, conn_id: 1126400, crypto-map: AWS-VPN
     sa timing: remaining key lifetime (kB/sec): (4373946/1580)
     IV size: 16 bytes
     replay detection support: Y
     Anti replay bitmap:
      0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000001

Crypto map tag: AWS-VPN, seq num: 1, local addr: 66.xx.xx.51

  access-list ACL-VPN extended permit ip 60.xx.xx.0255.255.255.0 10.100.1.0 255.255.255.0
  local ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (60.xx.xx.100/255.255.255.0/0/0)
  remote ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (10.100.1.0/255.255.255.0/0/0)
  current_peer: 13.xx.xx.30


  #pkts encaps: 549, #pkts encrypt: 549, #pkts digest: 549
  #pkts decaps: 149, #pkts decrypt: 128, #pkts verify: 128
  #pkts compressed: 0, #pkts decompressed: 0
  #pkts not compressed: 549, #pkts comp failed: 0, #pkts decomp failed: 0
  #pre-frag successes: 0, #pre-frag failures: 0, #fragments created: 0
  #PMTUs sent: 0, #PMTUs rcvd: 0, #decapsulated frgs needing reassembly: 0
  #TFC rcvd: 0, #TFC sent: 0
  #Valid ICMP Errors rcvd: 0, #Invalid ICMP Errors rcvd: 0
  #send errors: 0, #recv errors: 21

  local crypto endpt.: 66.xx.xx.51/4500, remote crypto endpt.: 13.xx.xx.30/4500
  path mtu 1500, ipsec overhead 82(52), media mtu 1500
  PMTU time remaining (sec): 0, DF policy: clear-df
  ICMP error validation: disabled, TFC packets: disabled
  current outbound spi: A42787FD
  current inbound spi : FF78BA5E

inbound esp sas:
  spi: 0xFF78BA5E (4286102110)
     transform: esp-aes esp-sha-hmac no compression
     in use settings ={L2L, Tunnel,  NAT-T-Encaps, PFS Group 2, IKEv1, }
     slot: 0, conn_id: 1126400, crypto-map: AWS-VPN
     sa timing: remaining key lifetime (kB/sec): (4373989/1662)
     IV size: 16 bytes
     replay detection support: Y
     Anti replay bitmap:
      0xFFFFFFFF 0xFFFFFFFF 0xFFFFFD55 0x557FFFFF
outbound esp sas:
  spi: 0xA42787FD (2754054141)
     transform: esp-aes esp-sha-hmac no compression
     in use settings ={L2L, Tunnel,  NAT-T-Encaps, PFS Group 2, IKEv1, }
     slot: 0, conn_id: 1126400, crypto-map: AWS-VPN
     sa timing: remaining key lifetime (kB/sec): (4373954/1655)
     IV size: 16 bytes
     replay detection support: Y
     Anti replay bitmap:
      0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000001

Crypto map tag: AWS-VPN, seq num: 1, local addr: 66.xx.xx.51

  access-list ACL-VPN extended permit ip 70.xx.x.0 255.255.255.0 10.100.1.0 255.255.255.0
  local ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (70.xx.x.0/255.255.255.0/0/0)
  remote ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (10.100.1.0/255.255.255.0/0/0)
  current_peer: 13.xx.xx.30


  #pkts encaps: 327, #pkts encrypt: 327, #pkts digest: 327
  #pkts decaps: 1024, #pkts decrypt: 20, #pkts verify: 20
  #pkts compressed: 0, #pkts decompressed: 0
  #pkts not compressed: 327, #pkts comp failed: 0, #pkts decomp failed: 0
  #pre-frag successes: 0, #pre-frag failures: 0, #fragments created: 0
  #PMTUs sent: 0, #PMTUs rcvd: 0, #decapsulated frgs needing reassembly: 0
  #TFC rcvd: 0, #TFC sent: 0
  #Valid ICMP Errors rcvd: 0, #Invalid ICMP Errors rcvd: 0
  #send errors: 0, #recv errors: 1004

  local crypto endpt.: 66.xx.xx.51/4500, remote crypto endpt.: 13.xx.xx.30/4500
  path mtu 1500, ipsec overhead 82(52), media mtu 1500
  PMTU time remaining (sec): 0, DF policy: clear-df
  ICMP error validation: disabled, TFC packets: disabled
  current outbound spi: 9F4A80A9
  current inbound spi : C87A19F0

inbound esp sas:
  spi: 0xC87A19F0 (3363445232)
     transform: esp-aes esp-sha-hmac no compression
     in use settings ={L2L, Tunnel,  NAT-T-Encaps, PFS Group 2, IKEv1, }
     slot: 0, conn_id: 1126400, crypto-map: AWS-VPN
     sa timing: remaining key lifetime (kB/sec): (4373998/2417)
     IV size: 16 bytes
     replay detection support: Y
     Anti replay bitmap:
      0x00000000 0x00000000 0x09200000 0x00000000
outbound esp sas:
  spi: 0x9F4A80A9 (2672459945)
     transform: esp-aes esp-sha-hmac no compression
     in use settings ={L2L, Tunnel,  NAT-T-Encaps, PFS Group 2, IKEv1, }
     slot: 0, conn_id: 1126400, crypto-map: AWS-VPN
     sa timing: remaining key lifetime (kB/sec): (4373973/2416)
     IV size: 16 bytes
     replay detection support: Y
     Anti replay bitmap:
      0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000001
```

Comment: Does AWS have a route to your 60 network back through your VPN?

Comment: Yes AWS has return route for `60` and `70`

Comment: ASA requires the ACL to match on both ends. Additionally, you need to exclude VPN traffic from NAT.

Comment: We do have NAT exempt, in my case if i send traffic from 60 network it bring down 10 net tunnel and 60 network work fine, if i send traffic with 10net then it drop 60 network, in short either one is working they both killing each other, it seem cisco doesn't like multiple interesting traffic ACL

Comment: How your 70.x.x.x worked earlier?
According to your first output you have NAT for this network or something like that.


`access-list ACL-VPN extended permit tcp 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 10.100.1.0 255.255.255.0`


You need to collect any configuration on ASA according your first working network and then try to repeat it for new one.
Site-2-Site works fine for dozens of network, if everything is configured correctly.

Comment: I have updated my question with output.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to put all subnets under single network object-group, then modify your ACL, crypto ACL and NAT Exemption rules accordingly. This make the configuration look nicer.

For example:

```
object-group network Local_subnets
 network-object 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0
 network-object 60.x.x.x 255.255.255.0
 network-object 70.x.x.x 255.255.255.0

object-group network AWS_subnets
 network-object 10.100.1.0 255.255.255.0


access-list inside extended permit tcp object-group Local_subnets object-group AWS_subnets   

access-list ACL-VPN extended permit tcp object-group Local_subnets object-group AWS_subnets

nat (inside,outside) source static Local_subnets Local_subnets destination static AWS_subnets AWS_subnets no-proxy-arp route-lookup
```

And please ensure to reflect the same setup at AWS end.

I hope it is helpful.

Comment: I have exact same setup i have add multiple subnet in `object-group` way they explain but still not working, it will bring break ping for 10 network if i ping from 60 network ip, so look like as soon as it see interesting traffic it stop previous one. also why do you have two ACL ? `inside` and `ACL-VPN`?

Comment: Did anyone configure site-to-site tunnel with multiple source subnet with single ACL ? it seems only one subnet can be active at the same time, so strange

Comment: Can i do `any any` in ACL but i think ipsec won't allow that to do

Comment: @Satish We often do like this when having multiple local subnets and multiple remote subnets for Site-to-Site VPN between Firewalls. But I am not really sure why that does not properly work with AWS.

Comment: @Satish The `insisde` ACL is normal rule allowing traffic from local subnets to reach AWS subnets and `ACL-VPN` is crypto map ACL for VPN tunnel. They do different things.

Answer (score 1):

This is so interesting. Solution is `any` ACL

```
access-list ACL-VPN extended permit ip any4 10.100.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

The Site-to-SiteS with AWS are different :)  They only support one security association with Cisco ASA (and maybe other vendors) that´s why the recommendation is to have only one ACL on the crypto map because if you add another it will with both and it will be dropping the connection between the 2 ACLs.

I asked this question in Cisco forum and got answer from there: https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/remote-access/site-to-site-vpn-route-multiple-source-subnet-over-vpn-tunnel/m-p/3204920/highlight/false#M17644

Comment: That is fine if AWS can only support the setup like that: permitting from `any` source then limiting the correct source in VPN-Filter :)